# calculate the total amount paid for y years if the rent increases by x% every year

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

How do I calculate the total amount paid for y years if the rent increases by x% every year?

I know that the rent for year x = startingRent * (1 + increaseFraction)^number of years.

And I could put that in excel and add em all up.

But is there a way to calculate the total in one line?

Comment: Sum of a geometric series can be found by a formula $$S_n=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}.$$

Comment: Can you please tell me what all the letters in your diagram stand for?

Comment: $r$ is the common ratio, $a$ is the first term in the series, and $n$ is the number of terms in the series.